# Filter table rows in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have uploaded an excel file in POWER_BI. In that excel file I have three columns reward date, employee name and reward name. Now I have to create a table in PowerBI where I have to list down all the employees who have received the same award three times(or more than three times) in a particular year. I am new to PowerBI please help me if anyone knows. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its depends what you want as an output. If you want a new CalculateTabel (not only visual with filter/measures). Then you should write code like this one:

Suppose we have such data.

[image]

And You want to show every Employee in the certain year with a reward count (grouping by reward name).

```
3orMore =
FILTER (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE (
            SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
                RewardTable[E_Name],
                RewardTable[R_Name],
                RewardTable[R_date],
                "year", YEAR ( SELECTEDVALUE ( RewardTable[R_date] ) )
            ),
            RewardTable[E_Name],
            RewardTable[R_Name],
            [year]
        ),
        "NoOfRewardCount",
            CALCULATE (
                COUNTROWS ( RewardTable ),
                FILTER ( ALL ( RewardTable[R_date] ), [year] = YEAR ( RewardTable[R_date] ) )
            )
    ),
    [NoOfRewardCount] >= 3
)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot at least you have replied..I really lost hope to get replies. Let me discuss it once again, for now, I will try your approach. Will get back if I have any doubt. Thanks again

Comment: all these employees( **received award >=3 in a year** ) should be listed in a particular column in power bi so that cards, charts, graphs can be made by adding that particular column in those visualizations. That table is absolutely fine but this additional column helps me to work more on my dashboard. Please suggest step by step if you can, I'm new to power bi. Please help ASAP. Thanks in advance

Comment: how to do that in _pandas_ so that I don't have to worry about the steps in Power BI I can directly save it to excel and upload it on PowerBI and then use that column for visualization. Please help.. Its really urgent for me I am continuously refreshing the page in hope to get replies.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't know how to do this in pandas (I never use this python library). I'm not sure what you need. Edit your question, add some examples of data, and examples of your desired result.

Comment: You can open a new question with `pandas` tag. You will get answers quickly. Don't forget to provide sample data and the expected output. @levis